# Hot to get all java running processes PID in java?

Tags: java, windows, process, pid

I have created the following code to get PIDs of all  processes. But it seems that `JRE` does not include `jps` and I should install `JDK` whenever I want to use this code. Does anyone know how to get all `PIDs` of all the running `java`  processes in java and not manually rather than my solution?

```
rt.exec("cmd.exe /k \"C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_73\\bin\\jps.exe\"");
InputStream inputstream = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader inputstreamreader = new InputStreamReader(inputstream);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputstreamreader);
String line = null;

while (true) {
    if (bufferedreader.ready())
        line = bufferedreader.readLine();
    else
        break;
    if (line == null || line.equals(""))
        break;
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: why don't you use windows task manager?                                                            if you don't see, follow below steps:                                                                        1. Press the Ctrl, Shift, Esc combination on the keyboard.
2. In the Windows Task Manager window, go to the Processes tab.
3. In the menu, click View -> Select Columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to list a process and its command line, process id in `Windows`, this is the command:

```
wmic process where "name='java.exe'" get ProcessID, CommandLine
```

That is the equivalent of "`ps -ef | grep java`" in `Linux`.

**Reference:** Answer adapted from the blog post of [Hung Huynh](http://unserializableone.blogspot.com/2011/10/equivalent-of-ps-ef-grep-java-in.html)

**Example of output:**

```
CommandLine  ProcessId
java  Test   620
```

**Example of output with `jps`:**

```
2312 Jps
620 Test
```

**Response Update:**

To retrieve the list of process ids from a Java application, **assuming that you use an Oracle JDK/Open JDK** as it is specific to Sun/Oracle, it can be done as next:

```
// Checking for local Host, one can do for remote machine as well
MonitoredHost local = MonitoredHost.getMonitoredHost("localhost");
// Take all active VM's on Host, LocalHost here
Set<Integer> vmlist = new HashSet<>(local.activeVms());
for (Integer id : vmlist) {
    // 1234 - Specifies the Java Virtual Machine identified by lvmid 1234 
    // on an unnamed host. This string is transformed into the absolute 
    // form //1234, which must be resolved against a HostIdentifier.
    MonitoredVm vm = local.getMonitoredVm(new VmIdentifier(String.format("//%d", id)));
    // take care of class file and jar file both
    String processname = MonitoredVmUtil.mainClass(vm, true);
    System.out.printf("%d: %s%n", id, processname);
}
```

**Reference:** Answer adapted from the blog post of [Vaibhav Choudhary](https://blogs.oracle.com/vaibhav/entry/listing_java_process_from_java)

**Example of output:**

```
88083: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain
88082: org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher
82789: org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.RemoteMavenServer
87892: sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

Comment: Thanks. but I want to get PIDs in java not manually. What I did myself is an answer but it needs JDK because jps is in JDK. I need a more robust way of getting PIDs

Comment: What I need is not just the PIDs. I want to know which PID belong to which Java process I mean not only java.exe but the full process name

Comment: If you run the jps that located in bin folder of your JDK it shows the name of java processes and their PIDs. The name of processes are important. Based on that I want to kill one of the processes.

Comment: Yes. No matter you run Windows or MAC or Linux jps is located in JDK. Just run it

Comment: I did not mean being not respectful. I am surprised which of my comments is not respectful. I said that What I need is another way to get PIDs. If you look at my question I said that I already can get the PIDs but I am looking for another way actually more robust.

Comment: Yes. You are right. What I did is running cmd in windows (or the samething in linux with its terminal command) and running jps that is an external tool. What I need is a native or built-in library to get all PIDs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but I use JDK 8 and it does not include the "sun.jvmstat.monitor.MonitoredHost" class

Comment: This is what I got when I run java - version: java version "1.8.0_91"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_91-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.91-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: It is oralce jdk I suppose

Comment: please note that we have it in openJDK http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/jvmstat/monitor/MonitoredHost.java/

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So it does not exist in Oracle JDK. We should use Oracle JDK. Is there any other solution?

Comment: No I don't know any other ways

Comment: FYI it works on the latest version of Java 8 (1.8.0_92) on Mac OS X

Comment: Thanks for solution. It is a better way